# Enable FTP/port21 on server?

Tags: rhel, iptables, ftp, vsftpd

UPDATE: When I remove the ftp_username from vsftpd.conf, I get this error:

```
500 OOPS: vsftpd: cannot locate user specified in 'ftp_username':ftp
```

I have a RHEL (Red Hat Enterprise Linux) 7 server that I am trying to run a Java JAR on that needs to  use FTP to download some files (ISO), but its failing because the server in-question only allows for sFTP *NOT* FTP connections. How can I quickly enable this/allow for FTP?

I tried installing and configuring **vsftpd** (followed this guide: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/install-and-configure-ftp-server-in-redhat-centos-linux/), I used yum to install vsftpd and I configured the `vsftpd.conf` file, but I still cannot connect FTP via WinSCP. I made sure these options were set to **YES** in the `vsftpd.conf` file:

```
anonymous_enable=YES
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES<br>
```

I am getting this error message:

```
Disconnected from server
Connection failed.
Service not available.
```

I also opened ports 20/21 on the IPTABLES service (I followed this guide: https://www.thegeekdiary.com/centos-rhel-how-to-configure-iptable-rules-to-allow-ftp-ports-2021/). I'm more of a high-level programming language guy and not much of a Linux guy. Can anyone give me a tip of what I could be doing wrong?

My only other option is to edit this  legacy code to use sFTP instead in Java, but its downloading multiples files in a orchestrated way, and I'm really dreading having to do that.

Comment: Use `netstat` to check if the server is actually listening on those ports. Also, did you restart `vsftpd` after changing the config?

Comment: @Panki OK, I see in netstat port 21 said its listening but the local address & foreign adddress is wrong. It says 0.0.0.0:21 but its supposed to be like a real IP address (10.3.185.92:21). I know its wrong because SFTP works and its listed with different local address/foreign address. And yes I restarted vsftpd

Comment: `0.0.0.0` just means it's listening on all interface (as opposed to `127.0.0.1` for example).

Comment: Its def. not working though, I don't think its a coincidence SFTP works but they are listed differently in netstat. SFTP has a entry when you do "netstat -an" and it says "ESTABLISHED" . I'm no networking engineer but I'm pretty sure this is misconfigured and why I cannot connect via FTP.....

Comment: First sentence confuses me a bit. You need to download files to this RHEL server using FTP, or you are trying to server FTP files for someone else to download?